# CRTP is taking more time than dynamic dispatch

Tags: c++, inline, crtp

Below i have shared the code for CRTP implementation and dynamic dispatch  . While analyzing the compiler code using https://godbolt.org/, i could check there is no  in lining of function call CRTPInterface::tick for CRTP case. More time is consumed as the function is not in lined

How to force the compiler to  make it inline ? I have tried using opton -finline-functions but no luck.

CRTP implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

template <typename Implementation>
class CRTPInterface {
public:
  void tick(uint64_t n) {
    impl().tick(n);
  }

  uint64_t getvalue() {
    return impl().getvalue();
  }
private:
  Implementation& impl() {
    return *static_cast<Implementation*>(this);
  }
};

class CRTPImplementation : public CRTPInterface<CRTPImplementation> {
  uint64_t counter;
public:
  CRTPImplementation()
    : counter(0) {
  }

  inline void tick(uint64_t n) {
    counter += n;
  }

  uint64_t getvalue() {
    return counter;
  }
};
const unsigned N = 6000;
template <typename Implementation>
void run_crtp(CRTPInterface<Implementation> obj) {
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
      obj.tick(j);
    }
  }
}

int main()
{


    CRTPImplementation crtoObj;
    auto start= high_resolution_clock::now();
    run_crtp<CRTPImplementation>(crtoObj);


    auto stop= high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration=duration_cast<milliseconds>(stop-start);
    cout<<"Time taken= "<<duration.count()<<endl;



    return 0;
}
```

o/P:  Time taken= 127

dynamic dispatch implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

class DynamicInterface {
public:
  virtual void tick(uint64_t n) = 0;
  virtual uint64_t getvalue() = 0;
};

class DynamicImplementation : public DynamicInterface {
  uint64_t counter;

public:
  DynamicImplementation()
    : counter(0) {
  }

  virtual void tick(uint64_t n) {
    counter += n;
  }

  virtual uint64_t getvalue() {
    return counter;
  }
};

const unsigned N = 6000;

void run_dynamic(DynamicInterface* obj) {
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
      obj->tick(j);
    }
  }
}
int main()
{
    DynamicImplementation diObj;

    auto start= high_resolution_clock::now();
    run_dynamic(&diObj);
    auto stop= high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration=duration_cast<milliseconds>(stop-start);
    cout<<"Time taken= "<<duration.count()<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Time taken= 57

Comment: Sure looks like it is inlined to hell and back to me: https://godbolt.org/z/zb8h7x What compiler/flags are you using? **Edit:** better test, using a forced side-effect to prevent it collapsing to a no-op https://godbolt.org/z/5vK8Kn

Comment: The compiler wont inline anything if you don't enable optimisations

Comment: I'm wondering if *static_cast<Implementation*>(this)" is confusing the compiler, preventing an inline somehow.

Comment: @SvenNilsson That `static_cast` is exactly the reason he is using CRTP, to avoid virtual dispatch.

Comment: Thank @AlanBirtles ...with -O2 optimization CRTP performance improved dramatically. IS -O2 optimization level safe to use ?

Comment: Thanks @Frank ...... is -O3  optimization level safe to use ?

Comment: yes `-O3` is safe, the unsafe optimisation options are enabled with different flags